# How can I add a custom caclulation form in post?

Tags: posts, javascript, forms, html

I want to create a dunamic form to make calculation for users. It looks like shopping card. I can develop this in a custom html,js and css.

But can I do this in a wordpress post? Or can I import a index page in a post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the block editor, then you could [create a custom block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/handbook/tutorials/create-block/) to contain the calculation form. Optionally you could [register a custom shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to print out the form. Afterwards you would be able to display the form on any post / page by using the block or shortcode depending on which one you chose to write.

In both cases you probably want to [create a custom plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/) to host all the code you write.